# how to efficiently create a range of float numbers

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

Suppose I want to create a set of float numbers starting from 0.1 to 0.00001 as first diving by two and then diving by 5. In other words, I'd like to get the numbers shown below.

```
0.1
0.05
0.01
0.005
0.001
0.0005
0.0001
0.00005
0.00001
```

For this small example, I wrote the following code snippet which works fine.

```
import numpy as np
def format_float(num):
    return np.format_float_positional(num, trim='-')

num = 0.1

for j in range(9):
    if j ==0:
        rate=np.round(num*(0.1),j+1)
        print(format_float(num))
    elif ( (j+1) % 2) != 0:
        num=np.round(num*(0.2),j+1)
        print(format_float(num))
    else:
        num =np.round(num/2,j+1)
        print(format_float(num))
```

My question is if there is a more elegant way to perform this operation given different rules. For instance, suppose I would like to get the number between `x` and `y` where the rule is to first divide by `k` and then divide by `l` in order. I believe this should be managable through `linspace`, but I could not do it.

Comment: Can `0.5` be the first element of the sequence?

Comment: Why linspace? You don't want linear. Seems more like a job for geomspace (if one of them at all).

Comment: Any particular reason for this specific sequence? Would be easier with an exponential curve to get a very similar sequence (but with less "clean" values).

Comment: Can you give an example of what kinds of "different rules" you want to use?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I was not familiar with geomspace and thought that linspace could be modified.

Comment: @ddejohn The different rules means that I would like to decrease the sequence uniformly at different order. For instance, something like "first divide by two and then divide by three"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.repeat(1 / 10**np.arange(1, 5), 2)[1:] * np.array([1., 5.]*4)[:-1]
Out[2]: array([0.1   , 0.05  , 0.01  , 0.005 , 0.001 , 0.0005, 0.0001])
```

Generalizing for any "pattern":

```py
def rates(smallest_magnitude, pattern):
    n = len(pattern)
    pows = np.repeat(1 / 10**np.arange(1, smallest_magnitude), n)[(n-1):]
    mults = np.array(pattern * (smallest_magnitude - 1))[:-(n-1)]
    return np.round(pows * mults, smallest_magnitude)
```

Demo:

```py
In [4]: print(*rates(5, [1, 5]))  # Your original 'pattern'
0.1 0.05 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001

In [5]: print(*rates(5, [2, 4, 8]))
0.2 0.04 0.08 0.02 0.004 0.008 0.002 0.0004 0.0008 0.0002

In [6]: print(*rates(5, [3, 5, 7, 9]))
0.3 0.05 0.07 0.09 0.03 0.005 0.007 0.009 0.003 0.0005 0.0007 0.0009 0.0003
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, but I'm not sure it's any better than your method.

```
import numpy as np

# Create the powers of ten:
a = 0.1 ** np.arange(1,6)
# Interleave the halves in between:
a = np.concatenate((a,a/2))
# Sort and reverse: 
a.sort()
a = a[-1::-1]

print(a)
```

Comment: Your code outputs ````[0.5  0.4  0.3  0.25 0.2  0.2  0.15 0.1  0.1  0.05]````.

Comment: Duh, I "cleaned it up" and changed "0.1 ** range" to "0.1 * range".  Fixed now.

Comment: just to point out, you can do `sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: The `numpy` sort method doesn't support `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
>>> np.cumprod([.1] + 4*[1/2, 1/5])
array([1.e-01, 5.e-02, 1.e-02, 5.e-03, 1.e-03, 5.e-04, 1.e-04, 5.e-05,
       1.e-05])
```

```
>>> 1 / np.cumprod([10] + 4*[2, 5])
array([1.e-01, 5.e-02, 1.e-02, 5.e-03, 1.e-03, 5.e-04, 1.e-04, 5.e-05,
       1.e-05])
```

Comment: I figured you'd just answer yourself so I didn't bother working on `np.cumprod`. This is a nice solution, and could potentially work well for their general use-case.

Comment: @ddejohn Yeah, didn't answer at first partially because their question isn't quite clear to me, so I just commented that suggestion, but then feared it might be wrong and I'd mislead you. Also partially because of inaccuracy of float multiplication streaks, although I just fixed that with my second version.